# Enhanced Dynamic Content File

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

I was looking into this Enhanced Dynamic content feature within Content Builder and viewed the Youtube video about it. It mentions that everything is setup into a CSV file with content (text, HTML, etc).

However, I'm unable to locate a sample file I can reference to start off this process and how things
are structured.

Is there a sample format someone can share?

Thank you

Comment: Man, you don't accept answers or contribute. Why should we?

Comment: @Macca, I'll definitely be more active in terms of contributing where needed. 

In the meantime, I was able to figure out the preparation of the CSV and how to reference the columns using ampscript strings in my email.

Comment: What @Macca asks is for you to mark answers as accepted or upvote them. So far, a number of people here have spent their time helping you solving your problems. While you have not provided any feedback or gratitude, to any of the answers provided - expressed in the easiest way by letting them know their answer was accepted. This is what makes us come back every day and help people like you.

Comment: @LukasLunow - Ahh.. Got it. Okay. Thanks for bringing that to my attention. Yes, people have assisted me in the past. Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: If I were you, I would go through the answers provided, and tick the mark to the left of the ones you find helpful.